# clang fail to complete kernel code automatically under Emacs company mode

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, kernel, clang, completion

**when modify some kernel driver, emacs does not complete code for me automatically**

eg. 
When type in "**struct devic**" and "**M-x company-complete**", i expect a whole word of "device" would be completed at least or a completion menu popped up.
But i get a hint "**No completion found**" in the echo erea instead.

Anyone came across same issue? Please help me.

Some advice would also be really appreciated.

**Clang version:**

> clang version 7.0.1-9+b1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)
>   Target:i686-pc-linux-gnu  Thread model: posix  InstalledDir: /usr/bin

**Emacs version:**

> GNU Emacs 26.1

**Content of variable "company-clang-arguments":**

> company-clang-arguments is a variable defined in ‘company-clang.el’.
>   Its value is ("-I/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/"
>   "-I/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/arch/arm/include/") Original value was nil
>   Local in buffer Makefile; global value is nil
>
> This variable’s value is directory-local, set by the file
>   ‘/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/.dir-locals.el’.
>
> Documentation: Additional arguments to pass to clang when completing.
>   Prefix files (-include ...) can be selected with
>   ‘company-clang-set-prefix’ or automatically through a custom
>   ‘company-clang-prefix-guesser’.
>
> You can customize this variable.

**Content of variable "conpany-backends":**

> company-backends is a variable defined in ‘company.el’. Its value is
>   (company-c-headers company-bbdb company-eclim company-clang
>   company-xcode company-cmake company-capf company-files
>                      (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
>                      company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)
>
> Original value was (company-bbdb company-eclim company-clang
>   company-xcode company-cmake company-capf company-files
>                 (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
>                 company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)
>
> This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>   satisfies the predicate ‘company-safe-backends-p’.

**Here is the buffer output of "clang-error"**

```
Mon Oct 28 10:56:16 2019
clang failed with error 1:
/usr/bin/clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -code-completion-macros -x c -I/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/ -I/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/arch/arm/include/ -Xclang -code-completion-at=-:230:7 -

In file included from <stdin>:7:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/kernel.h:13:
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/log2.h:197:15: error: unknown type name '__attribute_const__'
static inline __attribute_const__
              ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/log2.h:198:1: error: expected identifier or '('
int __order_base_2(unsigned long n)
^
In file included from <stdin>:7:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/kernel.h:15:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/printk.h:6:
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:144:13: error: expected parameter declarator
extern char __initdata boot_command_line[];
            ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:51:30: note: expanded from macro '__initdata'
#define __initdata      __section(.init.data)
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:144:13: error: expected ')'
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:51:30: note: expanded from macro '__initdata'
#define __initdata      __section(.init.data)
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:144:13: note: to match this '('
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:51:29: note: expanded from macro '__initdata'
#define __initdata      __section(.init.data)
                                 ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:144:24: error: expected function body after function declarator
extern char __initdata boot_command_line[];
                       ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:151:6: error: expected parameter declarator
void __init init_rootfs(void);
     ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:27: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:151:6: error: expected ')'
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:27: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:151:6: note: to match this '('
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:26: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                 ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:151:6: error: expected function body after function declarator
void __init init_rootfs(void);
     ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:39: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                              ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:290:6: error: expected parameter declarator
void __init parse_early_param(void);
     ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:27: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:290:6: error: expected ')'
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:27: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:290:6: note: to match this '('
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:26: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                 ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:290:6: error: expected function body after function declarator
void __init parse_early_param(void);
     ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:39: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                              ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:291:6: error: expected parameter declarator
void __init parse_early_options(char *cmdline);
     ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:27: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:291:6: error: expected ')'
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:27: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                  ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:291:6: note: to match this '('
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:26: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                 ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:291:6: error: expected function body after function declarator
void __init parse_early_options(char *cmdline);
     ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/init.h:50:39: note: expanded from macro '__init'
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold  __latent_entropy __noinitretpoline
                                              ^
In file included from <stdin>:7:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/kernel.h:15:
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/printk.h:145:24: error: expected parameter declarator
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
                       ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/printk.h:145:24: error: expected ')'
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/printk.h:145:23: note: to match this '('
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
                      ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/printk.h:145:30: error: expected function body after function declarator
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
                             ^
In file included from <stdin>:7:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/kernel.h:17:
In file included from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/byteorder.h:5:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:5:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/uapi/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:13:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/linux/swab.h:5:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/uapi/linux/swab.h:7:
In file included from /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/arch/arm/include/asm/swab.h:19:
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/swab.h:28:15: error: unknown type name '__attribute_const__'
static inline __attribute_const__ __u32 __arch_swab32(__u32 x)
              ^
/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/swab.h:28:8: error: 'inline' can only appear on functions
static inline __attribute_const__ __u32 __arch_swab32(__u32 x)
       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

**part of my init.el releated to company:**

```
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-backends (delete 'company-semantic company-backends))
(define-key c-mode-map [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(define-key c++-mode-map [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)
```

**and full part of .dir-locals.el file in /home/gnu/linux-5.3.6**

```
((nil . ((company-clang-arguments . ("-I/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/include/"
                                     "-I/home/gnu/linux-5.3.6/arch/arm/include/")))))
```

Comment: do you have cdefs.h, have you installed  `libc` headers?

Comment: @pickle rick  yes, I have cdefs.h in **/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/** and have installed libc. I wrote a test.c which contains a definition of function`static inline __attribute_const__ void fun() {}` and a main funtion which only prints a message, I compile this c file using clang and it succeeds without any error. And the execution of binary is fine.

Comment: I don't know why company compains about the **unkown type of __attribute_const__**

Comment: you get completion from company-clang for __attribute_const in your test file?

Comment: @pickle rick. Yes I do get a completetion choice menu when edting the test.c file and it has an item of **__attribute_const__**